# Calling a Servelet from Spring Rest Controller and return image from Servlet

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-restcontroller

I am having a Servlet which I am using to fetch the image from Database and display image to frontend.
**Servlet:**

```
@WebServlet("/jsp/DisplayImage")
public class DisplayImage extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userId"));          
            User query = new User();
            //fetch user details
            .......

            //write user photo to response
            response.reset();
            response.setContentType("image/.*");
            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            out.write(user.getPhoto());
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            .......
        }
}
```

This servlet is working fine.
 Now I want to create a rest api which will call this Servlet and return the user photo:

```
@GetMapping("displayImage")
public void getDisplayImage(@RequestParam("userId") final Integer userId) {
    //TODO call DisplayImage servlet and return user photo
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by redirecting to my servlet

```
@GetMapping("displayImage")
public void getDisplayImage(@RequestParam("userId") final Integer userId,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        
        String displayImageUrl="https://localhost:8443/app/jsp/DisplayImage?userId="+userId;        
        response.sendRedirect(displayImageUrl);
}
```